# Pivotting Mandrel Stolle Machinery Old in a new coat, Patent WO 2011156052 A1

Tags: patentability, wo2011156052

How come such a patent was already used under the Coors design and that the formalisation is taking that long, applied for in 2011 and no decision yet while two years would be a more than reasonable to come to a verdict.
we are a competitor being kept waiting, personally be believe this design is not new.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! To clarify, this site is not a direct way to communicate with the inventor or assignee of an application or a patent. It is also not sending your message to the patent office. We are volunteers trying to answer questions about patents, and we are trying to help people who think some particular application should be narrowed or not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The patent document number WO2011156052 represents an international patent application, called a PCT application. It can result in one or more patents if offshoots of it in countries selected by the applicant (each one cost $$$) are found patentable in that country. From the google patents page you can see "Also published as". Two of those represent patent application in applications in China and Europe. One is a patent application in the U.S. and one is [granted U.S. patent number US8596624.](http://www.google.com/patents/US8596624) It has been out for just about a year.

Separately, 3 years is not an unusually long time from application to grant. Most of that is queue time.